# C how to convert to hexadecimal integer

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, hex

im writing a code for converting a number to hexadecimal and im getting a random numbers as result.
at first i succeed to convert the number but it was in a reversed order (the first mod needs to be the last number or letter).
the code is a part (for cases of `%x`) from a big project that is kind of implementation of `sprintf` (so `sprintf` or `printf` are not allowed obviously). so the `buffer` is for composing a string without any placeholders.
thank u in advance.

here's my code:

```
int num = *(int*)ptrs[counter];
int tempnum=num;
int mod=0;
int length =0;
for(int i=0;tempnum !=0;i++)
{
    length++;
    tempnum /= 16;
}
int array[length];
for(int i= length; i>0;i--)
{
    mod = num%16;
    num = num/16;
    array[i] = mod;
}
for(int i=0;i<length;i++)
{
    if(array[i]<10)
        *buffer = array[i]+ '0';
    else
        *buffer = array[i] -10 + 'a';
    buffer++;
}
```

Comment: I guess you mean `array[i] + 'a'`

Comment: You should create a [mre]

Comment: What is `*buffer = array[i] + '87';` doing? I believe it should be `*buffer = array[i] - 10 + 'a';` or `*buffer = array[i] - 10 + 'A';`

Comment: Yeah, but even then I would be wrong, see @isrnick comment. I didn't bother to look any further than the first error I spotted.

Comment: @isrnick yes, that's what i tried to do (only your accurate and im not). but still in the second convertion (where it shouldve been b if my number is 123 for example), it gives me some random char.

Comment: This for is wrong: `for(int i= length; i>0;i--)`, it should be `for(int i= length-1; i>=0;i--)`

Comment: When `num == 0`, `int array[length];` is UB.

Comment: "for composing a string" --> code never sets the _null character_

Comment: Many problems with this code.  Sample code  to form a string of any base [TO_BASE(some_unsigned, base)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34641674/2410359).

Comment: marksman123 when `num == -10`, what result do you expect in `buffer[]`?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica its a small portion from the code. in the whole code it does set a null character, and the code is far from being done.. i know there is a lot to fix(such as handling with negative numbers ) . i just wanted to know if im missing something with this specific conversion of `%x` . and on top of that im only a freshman at university (computer science degree of course), so my code will be a little bit far from perfect :).  and your notes are extremly helpful, thank you very much for that.

Comment: marksman123 Note that `"%x"` is for `unsigned`, not `int`.

Answer (score 2):

The for loop of calculating `array[i]` should change to:

```
    for(int i = length-1; i>=0;i--) // i from (length - 1) to 0 instead of from length to 1.
    {
        mod = num%16;
        num = num/16;
        array[i] = mod;
    }
```

You do not need to change the buffer pointer. You can use:

```
    for(int i=0;i<length;i++)
    {
        if(array[i]<10)
            buffer[i] = array[i]+ '0';
        else
            buffer[i] = array[i] + 55;
    }
```

then do not forget at the null character at the end of buffer:

```
buffer[length] = '\0';
```

I do not see the declaration of `buffer` in your code, so i propose the solution above for the declaration:

```
 char buffer[length+1];
```

Comment: If this is an implementation of printf it may be convenient to increment buffer, as the string may contain more than just the hexadecimal integer, and without incrementing the buffer it would need a counter variable to keep track of the characters in the string. Also it may not be the end of the string right after the number, as more text may be added.

Comment: @isrnick I mentioned in my answer that i propose the solution for the declaration of `buffer` as `char buffer[length+1];` because i do not see any declaration of `buffer` in the OP's code.

Comment: Note code will fail to provide correct results when `num < 0`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Yes, it's better if we use `num = abs(num)` or exit the rest of code `if(num<0)` ?

Comment: Note that `abs(INT_MIN)` is UB.  With OP's goal, perhaps use `unsigned`?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica it depends on what OP want. I thinks `if(num<0) {num = -num; //or exit}` is OK ?

Comment: When `num == INT_MIN`, what value do you think `num` has after `if(num<0) {num = -num;}`?  IAC, `-INT_MIN` is UB.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica i got it. it seems that `unsigned` is better. Thank for your comment

Answer (score 1):

```
for(int i= length; i>0;i--)
                {
                    mod = num%16;
                    num = num/16;
                    array[i] = mod;
                }
```

mistakes at array[i] to array[i-1].

```
buffer = array[i] + '87';
```

I suggest you use:

```
buffer = array[i]-10 + 'a';
```

Comment: It is a start, yet OP's code with these fixes fails when `num <= 0`.

Comment: I he can't check for it , he can ask for help again :)

Answer (score 0):

```
printf("%i", (int)[any hexadecimal number]);
```

would print the integer form of this '[any hexadecimal number]' number